# Filter not applied after changing filter parameter in component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.5

I am blocked with a problem with angular two way binding and filter. I am using a filter by a parameter, and after the parameter value is changed in another directive, the filter is not applied. Here is part of code:

```
  <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
   <calendar-select ng-model="dailyTimekeepingCtrl.selectedDay">   </calendar-select>
  </div>
.......
   <work-timekeepings-day timekeepings="dailyTimekeepingCtrl.timekeepingList" 
            day="dailyTimekeepingCtrl.selectedDay"></work-timekeepings-day>
```

Component definition:

```
var workTimekeepingsDay = TimekeepingsApp.component('workTimekeepingsDay', {
    templateUrl : 'angular/components/work-timekeepings-day.html',
    controllerAs: '$workTkDayCtrl',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function() {
        this.isTkCollapsed = true;
        this.workTimekeepingTemplate='angular/popups/work-timekeeping-popup.html';
    },
    bindings : {
        timekeepings : '=',
        day: '='
    }
});
```

Component template:

```
<p> {{($workTkDayCtrl.timekeepings | workTimekeeping : $workTkDayCtrl.day).length }} </p>
<p> {{$workTkDayCtrl.day | amDateFormat:'DD MM YYYY'}}</p>
```

`dailyTimekeepingCtrl.selectedDay` is changed using a directive, being two-way bound to it:

```
var calendarSelect = TimekeepingsApp.directive('calendarSelect', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
        calendarDate : '=ngModel'
    },
    templateUrl : 'angular/calendar-select.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.dayUp = function() {
                       scope.calendarDate.add(1, 'days');
             };
        ...................
```

When it is triggered first time, the filter is applied correctly. After changing `dailyTimekeepingCtrl.selectedDay` in parent page/controller, the `day` bind variable is correctly applied. But results are not filtered by new value. Can anyone give a hint of what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you change dailyTimeKeepingCtrl.selectedDay?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I have updated the post with the directive used to change selectedDay. Basically is a directive that uses a two-way binding to update it. It shoudl be ok as it correctly displayed in component. I suppose there's something wrong when using filter.